# Syntax highlighting in Atom suddenly not working correctly

Tags: atom-editor, syntax-highlighting

In Atom, my code syntax highlighting has been working fine. Then yesterday, I rebooted my computer for probably the first time in a month and when I open Atom, all my syntax highlighting is incorrect.

The language is auto-detected correctly, but all the syntax highlighting is different and incorrect on all files regardless of language.

I've restarted Atom a bunch of times. Tried --safe mode. I have noticed that if I turn of "Tree Sitter" parsing in my config, that syntax highlighting is corrected for some languages such as Javascript, but not all.

Has anyone experienced this and found a solution?

I'm on Mac OS Majave Version 10.14.6, and Atom version 1.57.9 x64

Answer (score 1):

The syntax highlighting is determined by a combination of language grammar (which provides the rules) and your theme (which colours those rules). So, it could be either was updated since you last restarted Atom.

Another possibility is that the language grammar switched from the old TextMate default to tree-sitter. This can be toggled in Atom's core settings.

[image]

Comment: This solved the issue where TypeScript grammar syntax highlighting was all in yellow.